# React App crashes giving as useState input give an undefined error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-forms

I have create two states for my input elements and used onChange to manipulate their state. Why do I get this error even when I have declared the variables in a destructured array? Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong please

```
import { React, useState } from 'react'

export const AddTransaction = () => {

  [transactionName, setTransactionName] = useState('');
  [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
        <h3>Add new transaction</h3>
        <form className="form">
            <div className="form-control">
            <label for="text">Transaction Name</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              className="text" 
              placeholder="Enter name of transaction" 
              value = {transactionName}
              onChange = {(e) => setTransactionName(e.target.value)}
            />
            </div>
            <div className="form-control">
            <label for="amount"> Amount </label>
            <input 
              type="number" 
              className="amount" 
              placeholder="Enter amount"
              value={amount}
              onChange = {(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)}
            />
            </div>
            <button className="btn">Add transaction</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[My app crashes with the below attached error -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzmiT.png)

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR


src\components\AddTransaction.js
  Line 5:4:    'transactionName' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 5:21:   'setTransactionName' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 6:4:    'amount' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 6:12:   'setAmount' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 18:24:  'transactionName' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 19:34:  'setTransactionName' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 28:22:  'amount' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 29:34:  'setAmount' is not defined           no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables `transactionName`, `setTransactionName`, `amount` and `setAmount` are not declared. You can either use `const` or `let` to declare them.

```
const [transactionName, setTransactionName] = useState('');
const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
```

Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Oh that was such an oversight on my part, thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

you didn't declare your variables

change

```
[transactionName, setTransactionName] = useState('');
[amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
```

to

```
const [transactionName, setTransactionName] = useState('');
const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

const [transactionName,setTransactionName] = useState('');

const [amount,setAmount] = useState(0);

You can declare many useStates as you want, but if you want a much more easy and a better handling process you can create an object like.

```
    const [formData,setFormData] = useState({
       transactionName:"",
       amount:0,
    });
```

and on input you can have a single onChange.

```
const onChange = (event) => {
//grab the name and value from event.target

    const {name,value} = event.target;
          setFormData(prevFormData => {
      return (
           ...prevFormData,
           [name]:value
      )
      })
    }
```

Comment: This was such a big help, learnt something new today, thank you! Can we do it this way as well? 

`const [formData,setFormData] = useState({
    transactionName:"",
    amount:0,
  });
    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setFormData({
        ...value,
        [name]: value,
      });
    };`

Comment: No, you must mutate the previous form Data before setting another value.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same exact problem in one of mine applications.
Use state can not be used inside async functional components.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).